# Proving complicated predicate calculus sequent

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, natural-deduction

The task is to prove the following (wrong!!):
$$
\exists x \forall y P(x,y),\exists a \exists b\neg Q(a,b) \vdash \exists a \exists b(\neg Q(a,b) \land \forall y(P(a,y) \lor P(b,y)))
$$
I've actually seen the proof and it is over 30 lines... My main question is how on earth are you supposed to be able to figure that out without proof-solving software?

If someone can describe the method and the thinking strategies they use to solve a problem like the above, I'd be really grateful.

**Edit** Sorry, I goofed the proof. The real sequent to prove is the following:
$$
\exists x \forall y P(x,y),\exists a \exists b(a\neq b) \vdash \exists a \exists b(a \neq b \land \forall y(P(a,y) \lor P(b,y)))
$$
When posting on the stack, I usually rename variables and stuff to better understand the problem. But I didn't realize that the equality predicate is special so you can't change it. Sorry. My question is the same though.

Comment: Can you post the proof, or a picture of the proof? Looking at the statement I find it hard to believe that it's true. For instance, if $P(x,y)$ is true exactly when $x=0$, and $Q(a, b)$ is false exactly when $a=b=1$, then the conclusion does not hold while the premise does.

Comment: This statement is not valid ... can you please check what you wrote?

Comment: One way you can look at statements about binary predicates is graph theory.  The 2 assumptions are "P has a source" and "Q is not a complete graph".  The conclusion is "the 2 incomplete vertices of Q form a source in P" which.....is strange since the assumptions said nothing relating P to Q.

Comment: Well, the updated statement can be proven because equality has special properties not assured for some anonymous predicate, $Q$. Instantiate three witnesses, $r,s,t$, and an arbitrary example, $v$, so $s\neq t$ and $P(r,v)$. Now, either $r=s$ or $r\neq s$, by Law of Excluded Middle. In the first case we can infer both $r\neq t$ and $P(r,v)\vee P(t,v)$. In the second case we have $r\neq s$ and can infer $P(r,v)\vee P(s,v)$. Thus in either case we can infer $\exists a~\exists b~(a\neq b\wedge \forall y~(P(a,y)\vee P(b,y)))$ by generalising. Express this proof formally to verify its rigor.

Comment: Anyhow, the key step is to identify that $\exists a\exists b~a\neq b$ asserts that there are *at least* two distinct entities in the domain.  Everything else pretty much flows from considering whether or not the witness, $r$, to $\forall y~P(r,y)$ is one from those two.

Answer (score 2):

The statement isn't true.
Let $P(x,y)$ be $xy=0$, and let $Q(a,b)$ be $ab=0$.  The hypotheses are satisfied, but the conclusion is $$\exists a\exists b(ab\ne 0\wedge \forall y(ay=0\vee by = 0))$$ which is false.